# Why only last context can be pushed into array

Tags: javascript, canvas

Why is only the last context from canvas inserted normally into the array and
the rest are empty?

Here is my JavaScript code so far:

```
let c=document.getElementById("c");
let ctx = c.getContext('2d');
let s=document.getElementById("s");
let stx = s.getContext('2d');
let j = 1;
let mydata = [];
for(let j=1;j<7;j++){     
  loadData();    
}
async function loadData(){    
    
    let dataimg = [];
    let dataskt = [];
     img.src = `p${j}.jpeg`;
     img.onload = ()=>{
      
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,130,100);
      let imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,130,100).data;
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";
      for(let i=0;i<imgData.length;i++){
        dataimg[i] = parseFloat(imgData[i]/255);
       } 
       
     }
      skt.src = `sketch${j}.jpeg`;
      skt.onload = ()=>{
     
      stx.drawImage(skt,0,0,130,100);
      let sktData = stx.getImageData(0,0,130,100).data;
      for(let i=0;i<sktData.length;i++){
        dataskt[i] = parseFloat(sktData[i]/255);
      }
      
    }
    await mydata.push({
          input : dataimg ,
          output : dataskt 
          });
    console.log(mydata);
    j++;
   }
```

With one image it's working, but if I use an array of images all I get are arrays fulls of zeros.

Comment: setInterval(....loadData) was the trick...

Answer (score 0):

The fact you `await` in the `async` function, doesn't mean that the `for` loop invoking such function awaits anything, so that goes synchronous `1` to `7`, while the async function will be after at least one tick, invoked 6 times right away.

What you could do instead, is keep chaining within the loop so that all operations will be queued.

```
for (let q = Promise.resolve(), j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
  q = q.then(() => loadData());
  // or just: q = q.then(loadData);
}
```

This loop will resolve the previous *queue* and only after will invoke `loadData()` again, so this should work as expected.

If you need to do anything else after, define such `q` outside the loop.